# When does the day start on superuser?

Tags: support

I'm in the Eastern Time zone, and I've noticed in the past few days that a new day starts around 8 PM for me.

For example, when I go into my account summary around 8:15 or so, I can see that I've earned a small amount of reputation in the past 15 minutes as "today". I can also look at today's reviews, which show that a new day has started.

Last I checked, the day starts at 12:01 AM ;)

Comment: I'm on the west coast and I've noticed that the "day" starts around 5PM for me, so that would be consistent with what you see.

Comment: The day turns over about 8 PM (20:00) EST.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All Stack Exchange sites use [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

If you hover over your username, it shows the current UTC time on the bottom left of the dropdown box.